# Unhandled exception UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning for NodeJS application

Tags: node.js, postgresql

I develop a POC for a database application in NodeJS. The command below shall perform the query on database setup on db.js and credentials on .env, both on the repository https://github.com/brunolnetto/first_app . You may alter the key after creating a `dbtest` database on your local host and a user. The log below after command run `node server.js` on terminal is unexpected since the database dbtest on .env file exists locally..

```
(node:22285) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: error: database "dbtest" does not exist
```

I am glad to share my mistake with you.

Best regards, BP

Comment: How are you calling ``? What logs do you get? What exactly does "*The database query loads indefinitely*" refer to? Also "*when I submit the form*" is meaningless, there's not http code in your question.

Comment: I discovered a mistake on reference to .env variable POSTGRES_DB instead of POSTGRES_DB_NAME. I edited the question body and title for the new log error and github repository.